# Can not get value from img.onload event handler. Getting error Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: Event) => any

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a method in my angular app which checks image file on size and dimension validity and returns either false or true.
this is my function

```
checkFileValidity(file: any, multiple: boolean): any {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return img.onload = function () {
      const tableError = []
      const width = img.width;
      const height = img.height;
      console.log(img.width);
      console.log(img.height);
      if (file.size > 3000000) {
        console.log('size');
        tableError.push('size');
      }
      if (width < 1919 || height < 1079) {
        console.log('dimension');
        tableError.push('dimension');
      }
      if (tableError.length > 0 && !multiple) {
        return false;
      } else if (tableError.length > 0) {
        console.log('size+dimension');
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }()
  }
```

and on the line : return img.onload = function () { // I get the error mentioned in title

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are immediately invoking the function you are trying to assign to `img.onload` by adding `()` after closing bracket, `}`, of your function. This forces the function to invoke and your function returns either `true` or `false`. In the end you are actually doing this:

```js
return img.onload = true;
```

and you get the error. To fix this try to remove the invoking brackets `()` after the body of your function.